# In android how to unit test for a class is equal to another class where both classes are wrapped around by a wrapper class

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

I am using a wrapper class **GenericApiResponse** for api response:

```
sealed class GenericApiResponse<T> {

    companion object {
     fun <T> create(error: Throwable): ApiErrorResponse<T> {
        return ApiErrorResponse(error.message ?: "unknown error") }

    fun <T> create(response: Response<T>): GenericApiResponse<T> {

           if(response.isSuccessful){
               val body = response.body()
               if (body == null || response.code() == 204) {
               return ApiEmptyResponse()    }
           else if(response.code() == 401){  return ApiErrorResponse("401 Unauthorized. Token may be invalid.")     }
           else {   return ApiSuccessResponse(body = body)}
        }
        else{
          val msg = response.errorBody()?.string()
          val errorMsg = if (msg.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            response.message()
           } else {
            msg     }
         return ApiErrorResponse(errorMsg ?: "unknown error")
        }
    }   }
}


class ApiEmptyResponse<T> : GenericApiResponse<T>()

data class ApiSuccessResponse<T>(val body: T) : GenericApiResponse<T>() {}

data class ApiErrorResponse<T>(val errorMessage: String) : GenericApiResponse<T>()
```

and from my ViewModel **MainViewModel** I am calling a function from my **MainRepository** class:

```
 class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(val mainRepository: MainRepository) : ViewModel() {
.....
val source: LiveData<GenericApiResponse<GitResult>> = mainRepository.fetchApiresultFromClient(str_query)  
}
```

so in **MainRepository** it calls:

```
class MainRepository @Inject constructor(val mainApiClient: MainApiClient) {
    ....
    fun fetchApiresultFromClient(strQuery: String)
         : LiveData<GenericApiResponse<GitResult>> {

          var returnedData =    mainApiClient.getApiResultFromServer(strQuery)
          return returnedData
     }
```

**MainApiClient**:

```
class MainApiClient  @Inject constructor(val mainApi: MainApi) {
   fun getApiResultFromServer(query :String )
        : LiveData<GenericApiResponse<GitResult>> {

    var apiResult =   mainApi.getAllRepo(query)
       return apiResult
    }
}
```

**MainApi:** is the interface used for retrofit

Everything is working fine but I am having some problem when trying to implement some unit testing code for the app. I want to assert that when method is called from viewModel then the returned data is:

- is of type GenericApiResponse
- is ApiSuccessResponse
- value is same as i defined in test class; which is ApiSuccessResponse(TestUtil.obj_gitresult)

So far I have tried:

```
  @ExtendWith(InstantExecutorExtension::class)
  class MainViewModelTest {

    lateinit var  mainViewModel: MainViewModel

    @Mock
     lateinit var  mainRepository: MainRepository

    @Mock
    lateinit var  mainApiClient: MainApiClient


    @BeforeEach
    fun init()
    {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    mainViewModel = MainViewModel(mainRepository)
    }

    @Test
    fun setSearchQuery_callsRepositoryMethod_returnSuccess() {

           //arrange
         mainViewModel.liveResult.value = ApiSuccessResponse(TestUtil.obj_gitresult) as GenericApiResponse<GitResult>

        Mockito.`when`(mainApiClient.getApiResultFromServer(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.anyInt()))
            .thenReturn(mainViewModel.liveResult)


           //act

        var repo_response = mainRepository.fetchApiresultFromClient("java")


        //assert
           // assertTrue(repo_response.value is  GenericApiResponse<GitResult> ) //for asserting return type is of type GenericResponse //--TestResult- java.lang.NullPointerException
           // assertTrue(repo_response.value is  ApiSuccessResponse<GitResult> ) //for asserting return type is of type ApiSuccessResponse //--TestResult- java.lang.NullPointerException
           //  assertEquals(mainViewModel.liveResult.value , repo_response.value ) //for asserting 2 generic types are equal //--TestResult- java.lang.NullPointerException
        }

}
```

but all of the 3 cases i used for testing fails and shows result java.lang.NullPointerException.

What am I doing wrong? how to solve it? How do I write the function for testing all of the above mentioned cases?

Comment: Looks like `repo_response` is null. Can you show how you create `mainRepository`?

Comment: @Ircover : updated my question with the test class `MainViewModelTest ` and another 2 classes used in the app- `MainApiClient` and `MainApi`